# Finding the position of a specific <span> and scrolling the WebView to it

Tags: android, html, android-webview

I'm displaying an HTML in `WebView` and allow the user to jump between specific parts of that text.

When different parts of the text are being "selected", I'd like to get the position of the currently "selected" text part and then scroll the `WebView` accordingly.

Currently I already instrument the HTML such that it looks like this (the notion of "paragraph" here is a bit different than what `<p>` tag means, and it's not that important):

```
<p>
<span onclick="window.location.href = 'http://part.com#PARAGRAPH_0';" class="PARAGRAPH_0">part 1 text</span>
<span onclick="window.location.href = 'http://part.com#PARAGRAPH_1';" class="PARAGRAPH_1">part </span>
</p>
<p>
<span onclick="window.location.href = 'http://part.com#PARAGRAPH_1';" class="PARAGRAPH_1">2 text</span>
</p>
```

As you see, I set click listeners on specific parts and can also differentiate them by `class` attribute. Therefore, I could accomplish what I need to do if I could find a way to get the position of elements having a specific `class`.

However, I'll also gladly use any other approach that can work, including those that require additional instrumentation of HTML.

Answer (score -1):

You need to enable java script for the webview

try the following statement in the android code

WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);